# No sound on Ubuntu 20.04 , only Dummy Output on Huawei Matebook D16

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I am having a problem with my audio where neither internal speakers, microphone and headphone jack show up as output/input options, only HDMI shows up. I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed with dual boot with Windows installed in a Huawei Matebook D16. Audio works fine in Windows.

I've tried many solutions posted in all sorts of forums and nothing seems to work. These are some output logs:

sudo lspcl:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Yangtze Memory Technologies Co.,Ltd Device 1001 (rev 03)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c7)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
```

aplay -l:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

pacmd list-cards:

```
1  card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xd03c0000 irq 86"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:03:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        device.product.id = "1637"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "HD-Audio Generic"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 38468, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo-extra1>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1/#12: HD-Audio Generic Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor/#12: Monitor of HD-Audio Generic Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "LG IPS FULLHD"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio:

```
03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1637]
    Subsystem: Device [1e83:3e30]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
--
03:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Device [1e83:3e30]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
```

I've tried:

- Adding my user to the audio group
- pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
- Modifying /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf by adding:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
blacklist snd_soc_skl
```

- And many other suggested solutions

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try installing the latest available kernel, 5.14.14 or even 5.15-rc7. If it doesn't work still, you could file a bug report bugzilla.kernel.org/